# How to make HTML video play ALWAYS?

Tags: html, video, autoplay

I have a viral website, specifically about the votings in Turkey. I've created an 8 seconds video and want everyone who visits watch it.

But for example; I'm using Safari, and it's auto-play blocking does its job. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non muted autoplay is just simply not something that will be possible moving forward. Websites abused autoplay to the point were browsers simply will not allow it anymore. Chrome has a “media engagement” method where it will allow autoplay after a while if the user continues to unmute.